# C# Store type in an array

Tags: c#

I want to store an error in an array, but when I try this it tells me

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException is a type, which is not valid in
> the given context.

`Type[] errorArray = new Type[] { System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException };`

Am I doing something wrong, or is it not possible this way?

Comment: Type[] errorArray = new Type[] { typeof (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException) }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is use typeof().

```cs
Type[] errorArray = new Type[] { typeof(System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException) };
```

This way you store the type of your exception.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want to store the types of the exceptions in an array, not the exception itself, so you need to use `typeof`:

```
Type[] errorArray = new Type[] { typeof (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException) }
```

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator) site